# Image path in Magento keeps going to base folder

Tags: magento

I'm trying to add an image on my CMS page by using something like {{skin url=images/foldername/image%2011.jpg}}

With this, I should get a path like 123abc/magento/skin/frontend/default/default/images/foldername/image%2011.jpg

But instead of that path, I get a path going to the base like so
123abc/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/images/foldername/image%2011.jpg

I'm 100% sure that the folder works because I have other images on the same folder that works in other pages. I didn't change the package name so I'm not sure why this is happening for some files. Based on what I found on the web, magento looks for the image at the base folder if it can't find the file on the specified path but the image is there. Does anybody know how to resolve this and what else could be causing this?

Comment: Have you already compared owner, group and permissions of an working image file in the same folder against your non-working file?

Comment: Yes. While trying to figure out why this is happening. I tried different images. I noticed that the problem only persists for images with spaces on the file name hence %20 on filename instead of a white space.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I noticed how I got this problem only with images with spaces on the filename hence the %20 on the file path. Though I was given literally hundreds of images with spaces on their filenames, the easiest and fastest way to resolve this is to remove the space for each of the image.